# FastAPI read&write from file

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I started to learn python and I encountered a little problem.
I try to create little chat using FastAPI with only 2 requests, get(msg) & post(msg).

The massage using BaseModel from pydantic so it have 2 fields : nickname & massage content

If I use local db from the code it works fine ( I insert with post to dict then move it to the DB ) and it presented it nice and Json like.

But I want to use file and not local db, the problems I encountered are :

1. Can't make the write takes both fields ( it takes only nickname\massage )
2. It doesn't look like JSON.

### that the code I wrote : ( the # is the part I used DB which worked fine )

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

#db = []

class Text(BaseModel):
    nickname:str
    text:str

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return {'key' : 'value'}

@app.get('/chat/recieve')
def recieve_massages():
#    return db
    with open('chat.txt',mode='r') as myfile:
        return myfile.readlines()

@app.post('/chat/send')
def send_massage(massage: Text):
#    db.append(massage.dict())
#    return db[-1]
    with open('chat.txt',mode='a') as myfile:
        return myfile.write(massage)
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write [Line-demited JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON_2) to the file:

```py
import json

@app.get('/chat/recieve')
def recieve_messages():
    with open('chat.txt',mode='r') as myfile:
        return [json.loads(i) for i in myfile.readlines()]

@app.post('/chat/send')
def send_message(massage: Text):
    with open('chat.txt',mode='a') as myfile:
        return myfile.write(message.json()+'\n') #Make sure there is a line between the records
```

If the data you need to store gets more complex, consider using a proper database like [sqllite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer.
The writing now is give both fields, but the reading not working
getting this error " NameError: name 'json' is not defined
 "

Comment: Did you `import json`?